# Why is the inclusion an isomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Consider $X$ a path-connected space, $A\subset X$ a non-empty subset.

My textbook makes the following claim without any explanation, and I wondered if you could help: it says that the inclusion $H_0 (A)\to H_0 (X)$ is onto.

Why is that true?
It is easy to see that $H_0(A)\cong H_0(X)$ since they are both $\mathbb Z$, but why does the generator of $H_0(A)$ map to the generator of $H_0(X)$?

thanks

Comment: $H_0(A)$ is not necessarily isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. What if $A$ has more than one path component? In any case, to see what a map $f: X \to Y$ does to $H_0$, you should go back and try to derive this from the definition of $H_0$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, that's important :)

The suggestion about going back to definition didn't help me since I've already tried it and couldn't find anything usefull

Comment: @TopologyGetsMeTired, if you tried, it would be usefulfor you to tell us exactly what you did by editting it into the question. You must have done something wrong, or not understood what you did, for going back to the definition is all to this!

Answer (score 3):

An element of $H_0(X)$ is basically just a point. Take any $a\in A\,,$ then $a\in X$ generates $H_0(X)$ since any other point $x\in X$ can be connected to $a$ since $X$ is path connected, hence $x-a$ is a boundary, ie. $x-a\equiv 0\,,$ hence $x\equiv a\,.$